# Can I create the spill bucket for dynamodb Athena data connector after it has been deleted by mistake?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-quicksight, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I was following this [document](https://dev.to/aws-builders/finally-dynamodb-support-in-aws-quicksight-sort-of-2lbl) while setting the dynamoDB connector, but recently was facing some issues with the data not being displayed so I checked everything and couldnt find the spill bucket in the S3, It had been deleted by mistake a while ago.
I can't see any option of editing the lambda function of the dynamodb connector, I was hoping if I could go in the edit and give the spil bucket a location of a newly created s3 bucket but could not find any edit option.

Now, I know the name of the spill bucket that was created and I was thinking can I just make an s3 bucket of the same name as the spill bucket and the lambda function would automatically verify the location of the bucket exists?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply create a bucket with the same name.

Otherwise, the bucket name should be defined in the Lambda functions ENV variables where you can change the name to anything you like.

Comment: Ohh, thank you! so I have the bucket structure set up like this. 
project-bucket -> bucket1, bucket2, etc
and in the spill bucket, I had the bucket pointed as "project-bucket", is that wrong? I'm expecting whenever the content gets spilled, it will create a spill bucket in the project-bucket with the spill-prefix that I have provided. 
so a new bucket would get created in project-bucket, or is my understanding wrong and I need to set up a proper spill bucket with full path even if content never got spilled.